# R: Select strings that have the same general pattern

Tags: r, pattern-matching, stringr

I have a list of `strings` as follows:

```
> with(providers, head(Provider.Name, 30))
 [1] 1st Care (UK) Limited                 
 [2] 1st Care Limited                      
 [3] 229 Mitcham Lane Limited              
 [4] 24-7 Care Ltd                         
 [5] 3 Dimensions Care Limited             
 [6] 3 Trees Community Support Limited     
 [7] 365 Care Homes Limited                
 [8] 3A Care (Solihull) Limited            
 [9] 3L Care Limited                       
[10] 5 Star TLC Limited                    
[11] 92 Higher Drive Limited               
[12] A & I Care Home Ltd                   
[13] A & L Care Homes Limited              
[14] A & N Kachra                          
[15] A & R Care Limited                    
[16] A Better Carehome Ltd                 
[17] A.G.E. Nursing Homes Limited          
[18] A.R.M. Healthcare Limited             
[19] AAA Elderly Care Limited              
[20] AAA Medics Ltd                        
[21] Aadams Residential Care Home Limited  
[22] Abacus Quality Care Ltd               
[23] Abberdale Limited                     
[24] Abbeville RCH Limited                 
[25] Abbey Care Centre Limited             
[26] Abbey Care Direct Ltd                 
[27] Abbey Care Home Limited               
[28] Abbey Healthcare (Aaron Court) Limited
[29] Abbey Healthcare (Kendal) Limited     
[30] Abbey Healthcare (Knebworth) Ltd
```

My aim is to identify those observations that follow a similar pattern and then rename them accordingly with this pattern. Ideally, the output should be something similar to the following (please note particularly changes observations `1`, `2` and `25` to `30`)

```
> with(providers, head(Provider.Name, 30))
     [1] 1st Care Limited                 
     [2] 1st Care Limited                      
     [3] 229 Mitcham Lane Limited              
     [4] 24-7 Care Ltd                         
     [5] 3 Dimensions Care Limited             
     [6] 3 Trees Community Support Limited     
     [7] 365 Care Homes Limited                
     [8] 3A Care (Solihull) Limited            
     [9] 3L Care Limited                       
    [10] 5 Star TLC Limited                    
    [11] 92 Higher Drive Limited               
    [12] A & I Care Home Ltd                   
    [13] A & L Care Homes Limited              
    [14] A & N Kachra                          
    [15] A & R Care Limited                    
    [16] A Better Carehome Ltd                 
    [17] A.G.E. Nursing Homes Limited          
    [18] A.R.M. Healthcare Limited             
    [19] AAA Elderly Care Limited              
    [20] AAA Medics Ltd                        
    [21] Aadams Residential Care Home Limited  
    [22] Abacus Quality Care Ltd               
    [23] Abberdale Limited                     
    [24] Abbeville RCH Limited                 
    [25] Abbey Care             
    [26] Abbey Care                 
    [27] Abbey Care              
    [28] Abbey Healthcare 
    [29] Abbey Healthcare    
    [30] Abbey Healthcare
```

My question is how I could write something like a "general pattern" that enables to extract those observations that effectively have the same pattern. I have tried the `str_extract` but I think I am missing something while writing the general pattern.

```
library(stringr)
home = "[a-zA-Z]{2,}" # Select general pattern that where the first 2 words are similar
test = with(providers, str_extract(Provider.Name, home))
```

Does someone know whether there is a function in R that enables to identify patterns generally? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Regular expression would likely be the tool that does the heavy lifting for you, but you need to define specific patterns to match and their replacements.  Without this, you are asking for an AI solution which can somehow figure out how to replace something; this is beyond the scope of an SO question.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen.

Comment: If you know the exact patterns you want, then someone (e.g. @akrun) will happily give you an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen. The pattern should be based on the first two sets of characters (e.g. `1st Care`, `Abbey Care`,`A &`, `Abbey Healthcare` in rows `1:2`,`12:15`, `25:27` and `28:30` respectively. I think the pattern (`home`) should include something like `strsplit(Provider.Name, " ")`

Comment: A solution that could do my query could be using `gsub()`: `providers$group = with(providers, gsub('([A-z]+) ([A-z]+).*', '\\1 \\2', Provider.Name))` and therefore extracting  the first two sets of characters.

Comment: If you just keep the first two words, you will get `1st Care` from `1st Care Limited`, which is not what you want. Did you solve the task? Right now, it is unclear what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
    carehomes = c(
  "1st Care (UK) Limited",
  "1st Care Limited",
  "229 Mitcham Lane Limited",
  "24-7 Care Ltd",
  "3 Dimensions Care Limited",
  "3 Trees Community Support Limited",
  "365 Care Homes Limited",
  "3A Care (Solihull) Limited",
  "3L Care Limited",
  "5 Star TLC Limited",
  "92 Higher Drive Limited",
  "A & I Care Home Ltd",
  "A & L Care Homes Limited",
  "A & N Kachra",
  "A & R Care Limited",
  "A Better Carehome Ltd",
  "A.G.E. Nursing Homes Limited",
  "A.R.M. Healthcare Limited",
  "AAA Elderly Care Limited",
  "AAA Medics Ltd",
  "Aadams Residential Care Home Limited",
  "Abacus Quality Care Ltd",
  "Abberdale Limited",
  "Abbeville RCH Limited",
  "Abbey Care Centre Limited",
  "Abbey Care Direct Ltd",
  "Abbey Care Home Limited",
  "Abbey Healthcare (Aaron Court) Limited",
  "Abbey Healthcare (Kendal) Limited",
  "Abbey Healthcare (Knebworth) Ltd"
)
)

df |> 
  # we create a new column with the junk at the end removed
  mutate(shortened = str_remove(carehomes, "(?: \\(.*\\)|) (?:Limited|Ltd)")) |>
  # we then group by the shortened value. If there is more than one item in the group, then we select the shortened version. Otherwise, we select the original 
  mutate(carehomes = ifelse(n() > 1, shortened, carehomes), .by = shortened) |> 
  # remove the shortened column once we no longer need it
  select(-shortened)
```

We could also add on a "Limited" onto the end of all of the shortened ones if we wanted to, but it's unclear if that's what you want.